# jsp,mysql - passing two primary key to another .jsp page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm having a trouble about passing a 2 primary key. This page1.jsp fetch the session id of the user so it just display what it is foreign to him. here is the code

```
<select id="e1" required="required" style="width:100%" name="phase_id">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<%
try { 
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select d.phase_name, c.phase_id, a.id, c.p_id, a.empuser, b.employee_fname, b.employee_lname, c.p_name from logs_pms_t_project c join logs_r_employee b on c.employee_id=b.employee_id join logs_r_user a on a.empuser=b.employee_id join logs_pms_r_phase d on c.phase_id=d.phase_id where a.id="+session.getAttribute("id")+"");
                                                  while(result.next())
                                                  {
                                                        out.println("<option value="+result.getString("c.phase_id")+" title="+result.getString("c.phase_id")+" >" +result.getString("p_name")+ "</option>");
                                                  }
                                                  //con.close();
                                              } catch (Exception ex) {
      out.println("<script>alert('An Exception Occurred');</script>");
  }
              %>
    </select>
```

When the user chooses something, he will be transferred to this page2.jsp

```
<%
     String phase_id=request.getParameter("phase_id");
     System.out.println(phase_id);
    int phaseid=Integer.parseInt(phase_id);

        System.out.println(phaseid);
    if(phaseid == 1)
    { %> <%
    String redirectURL = "t_project_planning.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);%> <%
    }

    if(phaseid == 2)
    { %> <%
    String redirectURL = "t_project_execution.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);%> <%
    }

    if(phaseid == 3)
    { %> <%
    String redirectURL = "t_project_control.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);%> <%
    }

    if(phaseid == 4)
    { %> <%
    String redirectURL = "t_project_close.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);%> <%
    }

    %>
```

Now here is my trouble. in my page3.jsp I have a form, I can't think of way how to associate the form to be pass on the chosen item in the table that is chosen in the page1.jsp. The form in the page3.jsp has a foreign key in the form on page1.jsp. I think im getting lost at page2.jsp.

Comment: you can pass in hidden text

Comment: Im thinking the primary key of the `logs_pms_t_project` will be like travelling by a boat. Like, passing it to the page2.jsp, then passing it again at page3.jsp?

Comment: So in this case keep the value in session

Comment: It's like im carrying a long stick. I will make a query of the session that is foreigned key to the table I want then I'll just make it a variable to the page3.jsp? I don't know but I feel there is a proper way.

Comment: Hope you will not inject yourself by `"+session.getAttribute("id")+"`, springlearner is right, pass it with a hidden text as parameter, and why not include the page2 in page1?

Comment: @user5243992 because the page2.jsp is where i use my `if`s whereas i will filter what is their phase depending on the ID so the page2.jsp will throw them to their appropriate page.